# HTTP Error 403.14

Tags: iis

I'm setting up an MVC site on a new live server.  On other non-live servers it worked but on live I get this error

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

I have installed MVC 3 and MVC 4 but I still get this error.  I restarted the site in IIS and restarted the server but nothing is working.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

I am using IIS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the correct permissions for that folder.

1. Right click on the folder in windows explorer and click on Properties.
2. Go to the Security tab and click "Edit".
3. Then click "Add".
4. Make sure the Location is your current computer.
5. In the object names textbox type in "IIS AppPool\MyApplicationPoolName", where MyApplicationPoolName is the name of the application pool in IIS.
6. Click OK.  In the permissions window make sure the new user is selected and tick "Modify", or whatever permissions you require.  Click OK and close the properties window.

Hope this helps - be sure you don't grant more permissions than you actually need in a live environment, but as a rule modify is appropriate for a web application.

Comment: Haha sorry, I meant the root of the website.  Though I'm assuming you don't want to list the contents of the web root, so actually this may be more to do with the default page not being set in IIS?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not it.